# Redirect page only after success in PHP using Fetch

Tags: javascript, php, variables, fetch

I'm creating a registration system for a university project. This is using fetch to post the data from the form to a PHP file.

I want to transfer over a `$message` variable that is echoed at the bottom of my PHP page to know if the registration has been successful, or if an error message has occurred. If I can see that the `$message` equals my success string, I think I can do an if statement using `window.location.href` like below? Currently it is redirecting the page for any successful fetch, no matter what the response from PHP is.

I've tried using `header("Location: /index.html");` in my PHP file on the success line, but this also didn't work for me. I've spent hours looks for a solution but I really can't get my head around how to pass this variable over.

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(userDetails);

fetch("url/register.php", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "no-cors", 
    cache: "no-cache", /
    credentials: "same-origin", 
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    redirect: "follow", 
    referrer: "no-referrer", 
    body: myJSON 
}).then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.blob();
    } else {
        throw new Error("Things went poorly.");
    }
}).then((response) => {
    //Fetch was successful!
    window.location.href = "url/index.html";
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in your php file:

```
$response = [ message => "the message", success => true ];

echo json_encode($response);
```

You will receive a JSON response which you will use it to validate if the request was successful.

In your javascript code, you have to parse this JSON response to an literal object like:

```
fetch(url, {params})
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then((response) => {
   if (response.success) {
     // fetch was succesfull! 
   } else {
     // response.message could be used to show what was wrong
     throw new Error(response.message);
   }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use the URL's query parameters to pass the success message.  For example:

```
window.location.href = "url/index.html?login=success";
```

Then on the .html page you would have code that looks for the `login` query parameter and displays something if it's equal to `success`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm actually building an app using Cordova, so I think I have to keep my .html page as pure html for it to be able to read. So would this still work?

Comment: You'd still use the URL approach I mentioned, but you could use javascript to read the query parameters and show a proper success message.